# Django - MySQL Server has gone away

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using **Django version 1.7** and quite a few times I see the error below:

`OperationalError: (2006, MySQL server has gone away)`

I've defined `CONN_MAX_AGE = 200` in settings and `wait_timeout = 300` in MySQL's config.

Now as per my understanding from the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/), Django should drop the connection after 200 seconds and establish a new one, and therefore I should not get this error.

I have seen a lot of discussion around this error but couldn't find an answer for why Django is not taking care of this. Am I missing something?

Comment: Anything in the MySQL server log?

Comment: @KlausD. I didn't find anything in MySQL server logs that could help the case. Something specific I should look for?

Comment: That's not the way it works. If I would know what is written in the log I wouldn't have to ask.

Comment: Just meant if you wanted to know something that I might have considered not important.